# Quickblox iOS - Filtering custom objects with OR request

Tags: ios, swift, quickblox

I have a view which allows my users to use a search bar to enter either a username or full name and retrieve results of events related to that user.

Here is how I set up the query:

```
query.setValue(eventSearch?.text, forKey: "chatEventUsername[ctn]")
query.setValue(eventSearch?.text, forKey: "chatEventFullName[ctn]")
query.setValue("chatEventStartDate", forKey: "sort_asc")
```

However, this works as an AND operator. I need it to work as an OR operator. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either **ctn** or **or** operator but not both at a time:

```
query.setValue(eventSearch?.text, forKey: "chatEventUsername[ctn,or]") // not going to work
```

So, from my knowledge it is not possible. You can use one Search operators at a time.

Comment: @Igor Khomenko how to use multiple search operator with one field?